# frameset issue in iPad Safari

Tags: javascript, html, ipad, safari, frames

First of all, while I do understand that frameset is kind of very old and should be avoided. But in my case, i have recently started working on a client project and have limited rights to make major changes, like converting frameset to iframe code...

Having said that, here is the issue;
I have a frameset with 3 rows defined as 60,*,70

Now the 2nd row height is dynamic and depends on the content. The page displays fine if the 2nd row height is less so that all 3 frames are displayed correctly..If however, the 2nd row height increases, I am unable to see the 3rd row frame completely on the iPad. 
Actually I can see it in portrait, but not in landscape, which is where I think the problem lies...i.e. the height calc is based on visible height..

Also before you think of converting frameset/frames to iframes, I have already tried that in the past and iframes do not scroll using 2-fingers on the iPad (latest IOS 4.3)

Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: why not using jquery and .load()?

Comment: well its an alternative to iframes and framesets

Comment: But what will I load using jquery .load() ?

Comment: the html files that are loaded in your frames, see http://api.jquery.com/load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should create 2 stylesheets, 1 for each mode:
http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/ipad-layout-with-landscape-portrait-modes or http://www.cloudfour.com/ipad-css/

Comment: Ok..2 CSS is fine...But how do I fix the issue in landscape mode..given that I cannot change the display height at all...

Answer (score 1):

Put the Iframes css `overflow: scroll` and for landscape use `$(window).width() > 768` [as portrait width is 768] just my 2 cents!

Answer (score 0):

Beware : orientation detection does not work properly on iPad or iPhone in frames inside framesets - either in javascript or media queries :(